# Test Class Failing as Different Users

Tags: apex, customer-portal

I have a test class that is failing when run as a specific user, and I can't figure out why. The class is testing a trigger handler that inserts a case based on fields on another SObject. If the current user is a portal enabled user, it submits the case differently.

In the test setup it looks for a portal enabled profile and creates a new user:

```
...

// I'm aware I should be querying by license type here as it's more reliable,
// but this is how the code currently is and I didn't want to change it for this post

Patient__c testPatient = new Patient__c(Name = 'Patient', Physician_Office__c = testAccount.Id, RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Patient__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Standard').getRecordTypeId());
insert testPatient;

Id profileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE NAME LIKE '%Customer%' LIMIT 1].Id;
User newUser = new User(FirstName = 'Testly', LastName = 'Testlington', Username = 'Testly.Testlington@mail.com', Email = 'AdverseReactionTriggerHandlerTest@email.com', Alias = 'Test1', LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1', ProfileId = profileId, LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US', CommunityNickname = 'Testly', TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Chicago', IsActive = TRUE);

...

insert newUser;
```

The test method then runs as the created user and inserted the SObject the trigger is based on:

```
@isTest
private static void failingTestMethod() {
    .....
    User portalUser = [SELECT Id, IsPortalEnabled, Name, ProfileId FROM User WHERE IsPortalEnabled = TRUE AND IsActive = TRUE ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1];
    System.runAs(portalUser){
        Id patientId = [SELECT Id FROM Patient__c LIMIT 1].Id;
        AdverseReaction__c adverseReaction = new AdverseReaction__c(
            ......
            Patient__c = patientId,
            RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.AdverseReaction__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Systemic').getRecordTypeId(),
            .....
        );
        insert adverseReaction;
.....
```

This test passes for every user I've checked except for one: the user our nightly builds use. When the nightly build user runs this test, the insert at the end errors out with the following error:

> AdverseReactionTriggerHandlerTest.createAdverseReactionCase_severity1_portalUser -- System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

The nightly build user has the same profile as me and a different role, but the role shouldn't impact any of the involved objects. This shouldn't matter though, because the test is run as the user inserted in the setup. **That** user's profile however, doesn't have any settings for the inserted SObject, which I assume defaults to not having access.

I also added the following debugs before running as the inserted user and after running as the user:

> System.debug(Schema.sObjectType.AdverseReaction__c.isCreateable());

It outputs *TRUE* before running as the inserting user, but outputs *FALSE* afterwards. I would've expected this when running as the nightly build user, but wasn't expecting to get it when running the test as myself since it's passing.

Why is this test passing as one user, but not the other? And given the debug results, why is this test passing at all?

Comment: I found that during my research, but didn't think it fully applied to this situation. It could be a permissions issue, but if it is why does the test pass when running as most users? Where would the permissions issue be? The nightly build user and I have the same permissions, so I can't see that being the issue. The portal user might not have the right permissions, but then why does the test only fail when running as the nightly build user?

Comment: can you run it as the nightly build user in your org and see what happens? At least that way you can say it's not org based.

Comment: I've already logged in as the nightly build user and confirmed that the test fails when running it in the dev console.

Comment: I've also had a coworker log in who has the same permissions as me and the nightly build user, and the test passes for him. It seems likely that its a permissions issue, but I have no idea why it would be passing for me and my coworker if that was the case.

Comment: Can you break up the  initialization for adverseReaction into multiple statements, instead of inline, and see what happens?

Comment: I'll give it a shot, but I don't think it will change anything. The excluded fields were only text fields. I'll do some more testing and let you know how it turns out.

Comment: OH!!! I think it might be getting the wrong user in the query!!! in your where clause, add a filter for profileId

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94260/discussion-between-ryan-dinesman-and-ohana).